# Chrome becomes unresponsive for 1-2 minutes on a simple HTML page using official TailwindCSS but works fine after PurgeCSS

Tags: css, google-chrome, freeze, tailwind-css

I have a very simple HTML page with a drop-down list with 1100 items. It uses 2 CSS files - the official Tailwind CSS and a couple of my own CSS classes.

If you open http://212.16.185.250/test/working.html - it works fine both in Chrome and Firefox because it uses the Tailwind CSS after it has been processed by PurgeCSS to remove all unused CSS classes.

If you open http://212.16.185.250/test/broken.html - it works fine in Firefox but freezes Chrome twice: the first freeze is for 1.5 minutes when the page is loading and the second freeze is when you try to open/expand the drop-down list. This HTML file uses the official Tailwind CSS without any processing.

Any suggestions how to debug the issue without brute-forcing ?

Comment: I'm facing similar issue in rails app using tailwindcss. Any ideas how to fix this?